# [proxy_fcgi:error](70007)The timeout specified has expired

Tags: apache, magento, varnish

I am facing a weared issue with my Magento webstite... its goes down after every 1-2 days. Error is Error 503 Backend Fetch Failed. Guru Meditation. 
When I check apache logs it shows "[proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 3910:tid 140273111668480] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 127.0.0.1:55123] AH01075: Error dispatching request to :81: (polling)"

I doubts that it is issue with apache as it cannt return responce to varnish... I have checked few blogs and as per them Timeout need to be increased in apache.But i dont see any configuration like this.

After restating the server website works fine for 1-2 days.

Comment: Can you check your php-fpm logs?

Comment: Issue was with default cron set in magento admin... After removing default task list in scheduler of magento its working fine....

Comment: Great to hear. You should add this as an answer and accept it as solved for extra visibility :)

Answer (score 1):

Add these two lines into your `httpd.conf` file:

```
Timeout 600
ProxyTimeout 600
```